# Dynamic Views Title

Tags: 7, views

Drupal 7.

I have a view that displays all taxonomy terms based on an argument in the URl.  Is there a way to set the title to display dynamically?

For example, the I have a Taxonomy called Publications, where level one are magazines, and level two the individual issues.  If I go to the url for 'Time Magazine' which is 'publications/12345' I would like the view title to be 'Time Magazine Issues.'

I was able to get the argument in the title using '%1 Issues' but I want the name, not the ID.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tested the view and the trick seems to be to select the "filter type value: taxonomy IDs separated by , or +": (right click on image and open in new window to see full size):
[image]

For reference, this is discussed here:
http://drupal.org/node/1137672.
I would would think this is a bug in views, could be a feature ;-)

Comment: This solution doesn't work for localized taxonomy terms in title

Comment: Yes, many thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> This solution doesn't work for localized taxonomy terms in title

Didn't work for me either but it started working after applying this patch: http://drupal.org/node/1788832#comment-6495290