# Chage View title with taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 7

I have a Taxonomy Vocabulary as *People*. In it there are two terms *Board* and *Staff*.
I've created a view with two displays, to display the people content with respect to taxonomy terms. The view title is Board Members.

- When I access the  board page http://example.com/people/board the title is Board Members.
- When I access the  Staff page http://example.com/people/staff the title is Board Members too.

I want to change the *staff* display title to be like Staff Members? How to change it?

I've filtered by using Contextual filters.

Comment: Do you use 2 page displays for this view?

Comment: Yes two pages with single view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method add this code in the template.php

```
    function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      $current_path = drupal_get_path_alias();
       if($current_path == 'people/staff') {
       drupal_set_title('Staff Members');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. In the contextual filters click on override title and set it to %1
2. Specify validation criteria to taxonomy term and select the vocabulary
3. Leave the views title empty.

This will set the present's term's title as the view's title.

If need you can add "text" %1 to display the text appended to the term's name.

Comment: Don't forget to make sure he will overwrte defaults, not update them. If he will update them, he will end up with both displays titled "Staff Members"

Comment: Click on the board's display , where is the display :(

Comment: @dinesh : "Yes two pages with single view", the pages are called as displays in views.

Comment: then i have only one display and i filtered using contextual filters 
Specify validation criteria: Taxonomy Term
Filter value type: Term Name converted to term ID

Comment: Did you try the one here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/dynamic-views-title

Comment: Thnaks @Gladiator 
I did little more work to got the result.
1.I left the view display name as blank. 
2.In contextual filter, under When the filter value IS in the URL or a default is provided, checked override title, and placed %1.
this gives me the terms as titles as board and staff. So i changed the term names (Board Members and Staff Members) add changed the alias and done!

Comment: Hello again, guys :) Could you please edit what you figured in comments, @Dhinesh to a question and Gladiator to an answer, respectively? You know, for future readers.

Comment: @Mołot : sure will do now.